# Is $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^-} f(b + \epsilon) = \lim_{x \to b^-} f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f : \mathbb [a,b) \to \mathbb R$ be a function.

In the class notes I'm using, sometimes my teacher writes:

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^-} f(b + \epsilon)$$

And that got me wondering, is that the same as just $\lim_{x \to b^-} f(x)$? Intuitively I think that those are the same, the only thing that makes me think that perhaps they are different things is the fact that the teacher deliberately wrote $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^-} f(b + \epsilon)$ instead of $\lim_{x \to b^-} f(x)$.

Are those the same? And if these are indeed the same, is there any advantage on writing $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^-} f(b + \epsilon)$ instead of just $\lim_{x \to b^-} f(x)$?

Comment: Yes, it is the very same. Of course, we're assuming $\;f\;$ is defined on some left neighborhood of $\;b\;$ .

Comment: Do you have a bit more context, like where particularly did your teacher do it. I’m kind of curious

Comment: She did this in the context of Improper integral. Here I used a function $f$ because the main topic of the question is not integration, so I tried to simplify things. @Subbota

Answer (score 2):

You can check it as follows:

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^-}f(b+\epsilon)\stackrel{\text{subs.}\;x=b+\epsilon}=\lim_{x\to b^-} f(x)$$

Perhaps your teacher uses sometimes this and sometimes that in order to stress some feature of the function or something else...